# Is there a way to make Apache use a custom interpreter for a given file extension?

Tags: apache-http-server

I want to set a custom interpreter to use when a specific file type is requested similar to how requests for PHP files are handled but without making a custom module for Apache. I can’t set the handler for that file extension to `cgi-script` because the format doesn’t allow to specify the interpreter at the start of the file.

I have tried putting the interpreter in a directory reserved for cgi-scripts and adding a handler with `Action` and `AddHandler` for the file extension that points to the interpreter but <s>I haven’t gotten that to work and</s> I would prefer the interpreter to live outside of the document root.

Comment: What are your requirements for a permanent solution then?

Comment: @user1686 My preferred permanent solution would be Apache running a command like `interpreter /path/to/file` internally or running it like a CGI script that exists outside of the document root.